# Bluetooth communication between CM 530 microcontroller and Pyserial API

Tags: python, bluetooth, microcontroller, pyserial

I have a CM 530 microcontroller that has BT-210 Bluetooth module, I want my PC to communicate with the CM 530 using Bluetooth and Pyserial API.

In my PC (Python code):

```js
import time, sys, serial

# SERIAL INIT
defaultPort = "COM4" # change to suit your needs
ser = serial.Serial()

def initCom(port):
    ser.baudrate = 57600
    ser.port = port
    ser.timeout = 0.5
    ser.open()

def closeCom():
    ser.close() 

def sendPacket(packet):
    ser.write(packet) 
    time.sleep(0.030303030303030303) 

initCom(defaultPort)
if ser.is_open:
 print "hi"
else:
 print "bye"; 
sendPacket("\xFF\x55\x10\xEF\x00\xFF") # _1 (16)
sendPacket("\xFF\x55\x20\xDF\x00\xFF") # _2 (32)
closeCom()
```

The task in the CM 530:
https://1drv.ms/i/s!Aui23LOUVecGimYWdikg9hyGAs5i

I have tested my CM 530 code with the virtual RC-100, whenever I pressed any key the data received becomes 1 and if I pressed 1 or 2 in gives different sounds.

But when I tried to send a packet from the python code, the data received always zero, but when I check If the connection is open or not, it prints "Hi", which means that the connection is open.

Mabey the port I'm using is wrong, but I tried both COM3 and COM4, COM3 prints hi but it doesn't end, COM4 prints hi but the program ends normally.
https://1drv.ms/i/s!Aui23LOUVecGimcfMf7mVNec9MK8

Thie is info for the RC-100A/RC-100B: (I don't want to use this RC-100 but I want to do the same communication it does with the CM 530 but in my PC (Python code))
http://support.robotis.com/en/product/auxdevice/communication/rc100_manual.htm

RC-100 -- (Bluetooth BT-210) -- CM 530 <-- It works fine

My PC (Python code) -- (Bluetooth BT-210) -- CM 530 <-- What I want to do

Comment: I assume Bluetooth is neither **COM3** or **COM4**!

Comment: It's written BT-210 with port 4, why you came with this assumption?

Comment: Run `tools/list_ports.py` or `list_ports_linux.py` from `pySerial` package to confirm its port 4.

Comment: see the result https://1drv.ms/i/s!Aui23LOUVecGimjhK7_nX2K0Dfj_

Comment: I solved the problem, I just unplugged the USB link and it works fine!